# Rails Show from two tables not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have two models , `Place` and `Address`. And the models relationships are,

In `Place`, `has_one :address , :dependent => :destroy` 
In `Address`, `belongs_to :place`.

In new form in `Places Controller` I can add the fields to `Address` without any problem using `fields_for :address` in form.

But when showing , a `Place` details, I cannot get the `Address` details of that place. I don't know where I am doing a mistake.

In `show.html.erb` in `Places Controller`, I have,

```
<% @places.each do |place| %>
<p>
 <b>Max people:</b>
 <%=h place.max_people %>
</p>

<p>
 <b>Street:</b>
 <%=h place.address.street %>
</p>
<p> City: </b>
 <%=h place.address.city %>
</p>
<p> Pincode: </b>
   <%=h place.pincode %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

So , in `PlacesController` ,

```
def show
@userid=session[:userid]
@places = Place.find(:all , :conditions => ["user_id = ?", @userid])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @place }
end
end
```

which displays all the `Place` details properly but not `Address` details. I have searched through SO for finding my mistake but all I found was problem with forms. In my case, new form working properly, but not show.

Error is ,

```
  NoMethodError in Places#show

 Showing app/views/places/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

 undefined method `street' for nil:NilClass
```

In console,

```
  `Place.last.address.street` gives me correct data.
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that all `places` have an address object. And you can avoid exceptions using `.try()`

```
<%=h place.address.try(:street) %>

<%=h place.address.try(:city) %>
```

So, if the `place.address` is nil, nothing will be rendered.

Comment: I tried it in console, And it is working fine. `Place.last.address.street` gives me correct data.

Comment: you iterate ALL the places, dont' you? So try in console: `Place.all.each {|place| raise("Address for place #{place.id} is missing") if place.address.blank?}`. Some of the object has no the address.

Comment: thanks a lot it is working :) Yeah ,you are right. one place object was missing address. I changed it in database and it is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Valery is right. All places may not have an address object.

Try this:

```
<% @places.each do |place| %>
    <% next unless place.address.present? %>
    <p>
        <b>Street:</b>
        <%= place.address.street %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```